# How can we use function returns value in main function in if else condition in c. I dont want to use print in my Isprime_function file

Tags: c

File - Isprime_function.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "all_header.h"

int isprime(int input)
{
   int i, stop = 0;

   if(input >= 1)
   {
      for(i=2; i<=input/2; i++)
      {
         if(input%i==0)
         {
            stop = 1;
            break;
         }
      }

      if(stop==0 && input!=1)
      {
         printf("%d is a prime number\n",input);
      }
      else
      {
         printf("%d is not a prime number\n",input );
      }
   }
   else if(input == 1)
   {
      printf("%d is not prime by definition!\n", input);
   }
   else if(input == 0)
   {
      printf("%d is not a valid number.\n", input);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("%d Please use positive nonzero integers! Try again!\n", input);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

File - Isprime_main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "all_header.h"

int main()
{
    int input;

    printf("\nPlease Enter a Positive Integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    isprime(input);

    return 0;
}
```

File - All_header.h

```
#ifndef PRESENT_VALUE_FUNCTIONS
#define PRESENT_VALUE_FUNCTIONS

int isprime(int input);//check whether number is prime or not.

#endif
```

I use following command

```
gcc -Wall -o isprime isprime_main.c isprime_function.c all_header.h
```

I'm new in programming I have one small doubt.
this function works properly but in my isprime_fuction.c file i use "printf"  i don't want to use in function i want to return specific value and control Behavior from the main function how can I  do that because i want to use this function for get the prime factors of number.

Comment: You assign the return value to a variable, and use that like any other variable.

Comment: And if you just want the function to return a boolean "yes/no" value, and no printing, then do input validation before you call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

File - Isprime_function.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "all_header.h"

int isprime(int input)
{
    int i, stop = 0;

    if (input > 1)
    {
        for (i = 2; i <= (input / 2); i++)
        {
            if ((input % i) == 0)
            {
                stop = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ((stop == 0) && (input != 1)) {
            return ISPRIME_YES;
        } else {
            return ISPRIME_NO;
        }
    }
    else if (input == 1)
    {
        return ISPRIME_NO_BY_DEF;
    }
    else if (input == 0)
    {
        return ISPRIME_INVALID;
    }
    else
    {
       return ISPRIME_POSITIVE_ONLY;
    }
}
```

File - Isprime_main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "all_header.h"

int main()
{
    int input, result;

    printf("\nPlease Enter a Positive Integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    result = isprime(input);
    switch (result)
    {    
        case ISPRIME_YES:
            printf("%d is a prime number\n", input);
            break;

        case ISPRIME_NO:
            printf("%d is not a prime number\n", input);
            break;

        case ISPRIME_NO_BY_DEF:
            printf("%d is not prime by definition!\n", input);
            break;

        case ISPRIME_INVALID:
            printf("%d is not a valid number.\n", input);
            break;

        case ISPRIME_POSITIVE_ONLY:
            printf("%d Please use positive nonzero integers! Try again!\n", input);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

File - All_header.h

```
#ifndef PRESENT_VALUE_FUNCTIONS
#define PRESENT_VALUE_FUNCTIONS

#define ISPRIME_POSITIVE_ONLY -3
#define ISPRIME_INVALID -2
#define ISPRIME_NO_BY_DEF -1
#define ISPRIME_NO 0
#define ISPRIME_YES 1

int isprime(int input); //check whether number is prime or not.

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [the answer by Remy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35356686/434551) is on the right track. I would recommend refactoring `main` a little bit.

```
int get_input();
void process_input(int input);

int main()
{
   int input = get_input();
   process_input(input);

   return 0;
}
```

with the functions `get_input` and `process_input` defined as:

```
int get_input()
{
   int input;
   while (1)
   {
      printf("\nPlease Enter a Positive Integer: ");
      if ( scanf("%d",&input) != 1 )
      {
         // Error reading input.
         // Discard the rest of the line and try again.
         int c;
         while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
      }
      else
      {
         break;
      }
   }

   return input;
}

void process_input(int input)
{
   int result = isprime(input);
   switch (result)
   {    
      case ISPRIME_YES:
         printf("%d is a prime number\n", input);
         break;

      case ISPRIME_NO:
         printf("%d is not a prime number\n", input);
         break;

      case ISPRIME_NO_BY_DEF:
         printf("%d is not prime by definition!\n", input);
         break;

      case ISPRIME_INVALID:
         printf("%d is not a valid number.\n", input);
         break;

      case ISPRIME_POSITIVE_ONLY:
         printf("%d Please use positive nonzero integers! Try again!\n", input);
         break;
   }
}
```